# How can I match regexps like /\s*a\s*b/ without excessive backtracking?

Tags: regex, perl, backtracking

I am working in Perl, which uses a backtracking regex engine.

I need to match strings of whitespace-delimited tokens (I am parsing assembler in case anyone is wondering).  I am currently using regexps like

```
s/(\.text\n\s*\.align .(?:,0x90)?\n)\.globl\s+.*_?__stg_split_marker.*\n/$1/m
```

to do this, but am worried about excessive backtracking.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You should show your example string (useful to make tests). In my opinion the main problem comes from the `.*` that is very permissive. Other things: Why using the m modifier? Did you look for an assembler parser module before?

Comment: `.*_?` can be simplified to `.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is for any sub-expression that might do backtracking that you want to inhibit, surround the sub-expression with `(?>...)`.
So `\s+` would be `(?>\s+)`, for example.

Comment: Can this be combined with (say) `(?:...)` to inhibit capturing?

Comment: @Demi: `(?>...)` (atomic group) like `(?:...)` (non-capturing group) doesn't capture. But don't imagine that one of these groups will remove something from the whole match result. Note that if you want to make atomic a single token with a quantifier, you can also add `+` after the quantifier to make it possessive: `\s++` (if this feature is available in your regex flavour).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a lot of people try to use regexes where they're [not required](https://xkcd.com/1171/), and many people try to avoid them [where they're the best solution](https://xkcd.com/208/).  So I have to always start by asking - what are you trying to do?

What it looks like to me is that you're trying to pull apart some code.  Perhaps it would be easier to reverse that, and to always have it pulled apart and then combine it as part of the make process?  For this type of thing, I often will use templates to let me build code exactly the right way, and interpolate in the specific code for this build unit.  And then I avoid the regex issue altogether, which means I also can avoid developers doing something I didn't expect 6 months from now.

Comment: The code is output from either the GHC NCG (native code generator), LLVM, or GCC.  So I don't have control over the source (okay, the tool I am working on is part of GHC, so I do if it is the GHC NCG, but not otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there should be very little backtracking with that code. The whole thing is anchored by `.text`, and the other places where backtracking can occur will quickly abort. Still, there are optimisations you could try.

- Removed the need to capture (which slows things down) by using `\K`. Given what I said above, **this will likely be the optimization that provides the most benefit.**
- Replace `\s*` with `\s*+` aka `(?>\s*)` (prevents backtracking, which is safe because the next char can't be a space).
- Replace the final `.*` with `.*+` aka `(?>.*)` (prevents backtracking, which is safe because the next char can't be a non-newline).
- Replace `(?:,0x90)?` with `(?:,0x90)?+` (prevents backtracking, which is safe because the next char can't be a comma).
- Replace `\s+.*_?` with the simpler but equivalent `\s.*`.

```
s/
    \.text \n
    \s*+
    \.align [ ] .(?:,0x90)?+ \n
    \K
    \.globl \s .* __stg_split_marker .*+ \n
//xm
```